# The earliest story example of a software engineering workplace immersed into Virtual or Augmented Reality?

Tags: story-identification, history-of, technology, virtual-worlds

Virtual and Augmented Reality are topic of many cyberpunk or similar books, yet I cannot recollect of those authors who approach to describe a VR/AR immersed workplaces in a more or less "hard sci-fi" style i.e. going to more detail and following laws of physics etc. Assuming that there are still be many, let's reduce this workplace types to work of a software engineer.

To give an idea - but not a possible answer - let's take Viktor Pelevin's idea of a virtual cube-like tool allowing to explore facets of a phrase in ["S.N.U.F.F"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.N.U.F.F.) (2011) (my own translation):

> Grym uploaded the germ of his perplexity and sadness in the creative
>   unit, touched axes "heartier", "sincerier" and then the sub-axis
>   "salinger", which popped in the terminal sectors of the intimate
>   afterburner.

Another good workplace example which is quite close but neither correct, is the protagonist in the movie ["Zero Theorem"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2333804/) (2013) who has to solve that theorem using a 3D gaming interface.

Correct answer is the earliest example of a VR/AR workplace which appears more "hard sci-fi" than "fantasy", describing activities related to software engineering.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic here, but you can drop by [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe).

Comment: Descriptions of work places in SFF? Now you've got a list

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I was not even sure whether to discuss this in world building

Comment: @Edlothiad specifically, with VR/AR technology, this narrows the scope, or not?..

Comment: Stack exchange is not a discussion site. If you want to discuss things please come to [chat]. Re: your comment, it does narrow the scope, but it still looks like it's got many right answers. That's not what this site is about. Stack exchange is about having a few right answers. Not many that can all be right.

Comment: Whatever you edit this into, you're essentially asking for work**s**, which is off-topic. It doesn't matter how detailed you ask the answers to be, experience shows a good portion of the answerers will not even read your question past its title. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Please educate me how this question formally differs from the other one here, "books about people turning to dragons"
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127392/books-about-people-turning-into-dragons

Comment: That is identifying a specific story, if you were looking for one specific story, that would be fine.

Comment: @edlothiad so, could the story be "about software engineers, working in VR/AR workplaces"?

Comment: @J.Doe: Are you looking for a specific story? Then yes. Side note, there is an unofficial dodge where you ask for the earliest story with that element, but I'd advise to only do that if that truly is what you're looking for.

Comment: @J.Doe for future reference, a closed question is not bad. It's just not necessarily appropriate.

Comment: Certainly not the earliest example, but I'll plug The Lifecycle of Software Objects, by Ted Chiang. They spend much of the story developing companion AIs in a virtual workplace. Fairly early by my standards, but not specifically a software workplace is Permutation City, by Greg Egan. And for VR workplaces in sci-fi so hard it's basically philosophy, try Age of Em, by Robin Hanson.

Comment: How substantial is the vr supposed to be? Neal stephenson’s Snow Crash is much more hard sci wrt to software dev than weapons, energy and mind control.

Comment: In Don Kingsbury's *Psychohistorical Crisis*, people have "fams" -- devices plugged directly to their brain that supply extra memory, extra calculation and augmented reality.